# App Engine not iterating over a cursor?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, cursor, iteration, jinja2

I perform an app engine query to get a cursor (wrec), and the code shows the number of records correctly by iterating. But then "for rec in wrec" does not run (no logging.info inside this loop).

There's also a GQL SELECT of the same table, with another cursor (wikiCursor) that jinja2 renders properly. Here's the part that doesn't work:

```
wrec = Wiki.all().ancestor(wiki_key()).filter('pagename >=', findPage).filter('pagename <', findPage + u'\ufffd').run()
foundRecs = sum(1 for _ in wrec) 
logging.info("Class WikiPage: foundRecs is %s", foundRecs)
aFoundRecs = []
if foundRecs > 0:   
    for rec in wrec:
        logging.info("Class WikiPage: value is %s", wrec.pagename)
        aFoundRecs.append(rec.pagename)
    self.render("permalink.html", userRec=self.userRec, wikipage=pagename,
        wikiCursor=wikiCursor, wrec=wrec, foundRecs=foundRecs)
else:
    errorText = "Could not find anything for your entry."
    self.render("permalink.html", userRec=self.userRec, wikipage=pagename, wikiCursor=wikiCursor, error=errorText)
```

Here is a portion of the log, showing the first logging.info statement, but not the second:

```
INFO     2014-09-15 19:35:29,525 main.py:410] Class WikiPage: foundRecs is 3
INFO     2014-09-15 19:35:29,581 module.py:652] default: "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 3058
```

Why is the wrec for loop not running?

Comment: Hi, thank you for finding that. I changed it, but the info statement still does not appear in the log file. It's like the iteration refuses to run for some reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use sum to count, the query already iterates until the end. That is expected behavior that if you try to iterate over it again, it won't work (because it already at the ends)

Comment: That solved my problem. I didn't realize that iterables stop working. Thank you so much!